# How to change from Decode Html to text normal

Tags: html, jquery, kendo-ui

I have change value in textarea to Decode. I want change from value Decode Html to text normal. How I do it?

```
        $("#editor").kendoTextArea({
            change: function (e) {
                var value = this.value();
                var decoded = $("textarea").html(value).text();
                $("#9").text(decoded);
            }
        });
```

result example: < strong >sadsadasdas< /strong >.
I want: < strong >sadsadasdas< /strong > =to=> sadsadasdas (normal text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a `kendoTextArea` example for you in changing HTML to text. Try this in the DOJO. The HTML is changed into text after two seconds.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.330/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.330/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<textarea id="description" style="width: 100%;"></textarea>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var textArea = $("#description").kendoTextArea({
            value: "<b>Bold text</b>",
            rows:5,
            change: function(e) {
                var value = e.sender.value();
                e.sender.value($(value).text());
            },
        }).data("kendoTextArea");

        setTimeout(function() {
            textArea.trigger("change");
        }, 2000);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```